# Google Maps API V3 -> Utilize MarkerCluster but have the clusters themselves be specific to a drawn polygon/region?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Ok, let me preface this question with the fact that I have created a lot of google maps, but they have been strictly markers and polylines denoting routes and a couple with some handler interaction.

Now I am looking to show basically a map of the world, mostly North America and I want to split this continent into my predefined regions with some lats/lngs that I have.  Using these regions I want to draw something like a polygon with a light opacity and different color per region.

I then want to use marker clustering but I want the clusters to be specific to these regions.  I have looked around but I haven't found an example like this.  I have seen pages that say you can do this but not how you would go about doing this.  Again, I am definitely a noob when it comes to drawing polygons and using the marker cluster.  I know this question is fairly vague but just looking for an example/idea to start off of, and more so I don't want to write a bunch of code against this specific api and then find out that it is not possible.

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated....Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, but will require a rewrite of the MarkerClusterer (probably will simplify it).

You will need to determine how you are going to represent and load the cluster boundary polygons (KML, GeoJSON, native Google Maps API v3 polygons) and probably use the [google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) instead of LatLngBounds.contains to determine which cluster "owns" a marker.